# Faster way to iterate over dictionary and dataframe together?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary and a DataFrame with same keys/columns.
The DataFrame, however, is missing some data, which I will fill in using the dictionary.
This is a minimal example and my dataset is much larger.

```py
mydict = {'one': ['foo', 'bar'], 'two': ['foo', 'bar']}
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'one': ['N/A', 'bar'], 'two': ['foo', 'N/A'], 'foo': ['foo', 'bar'], 'bar': ['foo', 'bar']})

def myfunc(mydict):
    for i,k in mydict.items():
            for m in k:
                mydf[i].replace(to_replace='N/A', value=mydf[m], inplace=True)


for f,g in mydf.iterrows():
        for h in g:
            if h != 'N/A':
                myfunc(mydict)

for i,v in mydict.items(): 
    mydf.drop(columns=v, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
```

When I run my function on a larger dataset, the kernel won't stop running. What would be a faster way to do this?
I want to try to use df.apply() or vectorize the fucntion but don't know how to. The output for the example above looks like:

```
    one two
0   foo foo
1   bar bar
```

Comment: Would the dict have as many as values as the rows in the df?

Comment: no. The dict has an many values as the columns in the df.

Comment: why not just make your dataframe from the dict? `pd.DataFrame(mydict)`

Comment: Why are you using the string `"N/A"` instead of proper NaN values? _I want to try to use df.apply() or vectorize the fucntion but don't know how to._ What do you mean you don't know how to? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it should give you what you want.

```
# Fill the values using your dictionary
for k, v in mydict.items():
    mydf[k] = v  

# Drop the columns you don't want
mydf.drop(columns=['foo','bar'], inplace=True)
```

And you will get this:

```
    one two
0   foo foo
1   bar bar
```

Comment: I also want to drop the df[v] columns. If you see my output in the question, it is a bit different.

Comment: oh you want to drop the `foo` and `bar` columns?

Comment: @RohanGupta That's another question entirely, it's unrelated to the problem. Why fill in the missing values if you're going to drop the column anyway?